# Location and Gmap relationship - what is alternative to show Location items on a google map?

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

Recently the Gmap module has described itself on the module page as now being a 'legacy' module.  If you have used this recipe in the past, you may be familiar with the long and unresolved issue of the project trying hard to migrate to Google Maps API v3.

Unfortunately, because of this issue, the Location and Gmap combination is no longer a viable solution to show Location based items on a google map.

What would be the current Drupal 7 equivalent recipe? I would prefer to keep the Location module in use as I need it for proximity searches, but I am open to suggestions.  Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the book *Mapping with Drupal*, the alternate to Location/Gmap is Geofield/Geocoder/Addressfield.  However, proximity searches don't currently work with this solution.

I have been experimenting with a lot of modules in this space and unfortunately Drupal 7 is behind the times in this regard.

Comment: That's what I am finding as well.  So far, in order to have the proximity search, I have kept locations module in play, but eliminated the gmaps module. Instead, I created a very simple module that takes the geo coords from the location field, appends them to the Google Maps URL parameters (maps.google.com/?q=43,121), and then I embed that as a google maps <iframe> into my node. eh, not the best solution, but until gmaps is fully updated (if ever) I think that will solve my issue for this one project.